# Importing Delphi Web Services into Java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, delphi

I have a web server built in Delphi, and I'm trying to consume its web services on Java (I'm using Eclipse IDE) by creating a Web Service Client through the Eclipse wizard. The Web Services Explorer recognice the WSDL file, but when trying to create the client, the wizard says there's an "unexpected attribute" and does not create any file.

This is my wsdl file (the one that my Delphi Web Server publishes).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ITSOAPWebServiceservice" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/">
  <message name="WebMethod0Request">
    <part name="Document" type="xs:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="WebMethod0Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="ITSOAPWebService">
    <operation name="WebMethod">
      <input message="tns:WebMethod0Request"/>
      <output message="tns:WebMethod0Response"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="ITSOAPWebServicebinding" type="tns:ITSOAPWebService">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="WebMethod">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:TWebServiceIntf1-ITSOAPWebService#WebMethod" style="rpc"/>
      <input message="tns:WebMethod0Request">
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:TWebServiceIntf1-ITSOAPWebService"/>
      </input>
      <output message="tns:WebMethod0Response">
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:TWebServiceIntf1-ITSOAPWebService"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="ITSOAPWebServiceservice">
    <port name="ITSOAPWebServicePort" binding="tns:ITSOAPWebServicebinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:1024/soap/ITSOAPWebService"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Now, Eclipse says that the "message" attribute in both:

```
definicions.binding.operation.input  
definitions.binding.operation.output
```

is unexpected. I know it's redundant, since these are already defined in

```
definitions.portType.operation.input  
definitions.portType.operation.output
```

but still, I can't import the web service.

My Java app will be running on a JBoss 4.2 server, but I thought it'd be easier to create the client as a Java Utility Project (since it creates only one project instead of two).

So, any idea on how to make Eclipse ignore these attributes, or Delphi not to publish them?

Answer (score 2):

Try Axis2 from apache, look at the wsdl2java command to generate a java client to your Delphi web service. If you are using Ant for your build there is a task to generate your client.

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_3/userguide-creatingclients.html